# API url for instant purchase in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I am new for Magento and want to create **REST API** of **instant purchase** functionality for mobile application using Magento version 2.2.6. I have configured instant purchase option for site and it's working fine.

To create API for instant purchase, I have googled but unfortunately did not find api url for instant purchase. I have already worked for magento API like **add to card, list products**...etc but unable to create for instant purchase. So could someone suggest me if possible, how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instant purchase `Magento_InstantPurchase` does not have API points. It is only built for Magento own frontend. If you want to implement for  Rest Api then you have to build the module yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Amit! Could suggest something about how to build module for this?